# QGIS inconsistent label positions in PNG / PDF layout exports

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling

As part of my QGIS project's Continuous Integration workflow I have a process that generates "before" and "after" images from project Layouts, to visually show what has changed between git commits. This is really useful in reviewing / approving changes to the project's geometry data.

However one problem I've encountered is false-positives, where there has been no change to the underlying data but QGIS has rendered labels for the same line data differently across two exports. I have Label Anchoring configured as follows:

[image]
I have tried explicitly setting label positions differently, but "Centre of Line" and "Preferred Placement Hint" give the best aesthetics. Changing "Preferred" to "Strict" fixes the moving label problem but does not give as good an end result as it prevents QGIS from applying its own positioning logic.

Here is one example of a label move when no data has changed (see bottom-right):

[image]

Is there anything else I can to introduce more consistency to label positioning across Layout exports? For this before/after image the underlying data and the layout configuration are identical, but there is seemingly some pseudo-random element in positioning.